# Force acting on the surface during aspiration of elastic body into the pipe

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, solid-mechanics

Assume we have a pipe and a spherical elastic body Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiJhC.png) suspended in incompressible fluid. Due to the pressure difference, the sphere is partially sucked into the pipe so there is an equilibrium between pressure force and body tension.

The question is how the force is acting on the part of the membrane inside the pipe. Assuming there is a uniform triangulation of the surface, does every triangle inside the pipe feel the same sucking force? Or, may be, the force acting on the triangle depends on the area of the projection of this triangle into the cross section of the pipe? On the figure I showed two triangles t1 and t2 with the corresponding acting forces, so assuming that their areas are equal but the areas of the projections to the cross section are not, do we have f1=f2 or f2>f1?

[image: Fig 1]

UPD: New figure to illustrate @lemon answer
[image]

Comment: The sucking force *normal* to the surface will be the same at all points, so f2>f1.

Comment: @lemon you should turn your comment into an answer with a diagram.

Comment: @lemon so you mean that the force acting on each triangle is acting in normal direction and all of these forces are equal in magnitude. could you provide a reference or give a hint of a proof? And also, if we continue sucking the ball and the indentation length L > R (radius of the half sphere inside the pipe) than the part of the surface between the contact circle and this half sphere will have cylindrical shape. Will sucking force also act on this part?  As an example: http://d3md5dngttnvbj.cloudfront.net/content/bloodjournal/103/3/1131/F2.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sucking force will act normal to the surface at all points (so f2>f1). That's simply the nature of pressure: it imposes a force on any surface element that is normal to that element (this follows from the fact that the particles in the fluid transfer momentum tangentially in each direction with equal probability which thus cancel out).

If the bulge forms a cylinder within the tube then the sucking force no longer acts directly on the parts of the elastic body in contact with the tube. This is because, by inflating, the fluid has been expelled from those regions. The forces then acting are the internal pressure, the stress of the body's stretched surface, and the reactive force from the tube's wall.

Comment: I added an updated figure to illustrate what you have said. Small arrows orthogonal to the sucked surface depict force acting on each triangle (call it g_i to distinguish from the projection to x-axis Pr_x{g_i} = f_i). If I understood everything correctly, am I right also that the total force acting on the sucked surface is F=dP*pi*R^2 = sum{Pr_x{g_i}}?

Comment: @KirillLykov Due to the symmetry, yes, that would be the total force. Although I can't imagine knowing the total force would be particularly helpful in this system.

Comment: In this case, what is the norm of vector g_i? I think |g_i| = |g| F/(pi * R^2)  because \int_A  <norm to sphere, (1,0,0)> * |g|dA=|g|*pi * R^2

Comment: Finally, I got it: g=normal * dP * dS where normal is normal to the triangle, dS is the area of the triangle